# ImportError: cannot import name 'itemgetter' from 'operator'

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, import

Help me with my problem, I've made some file that named *'percobaan.py'* and I ran it with cmd and it's got some error. the error say `ImportError: cannot import name 'itemgetter' from 'operator'`, But if I run my code in python IDLE the code runs without any errors.

**My code:**

```
import tkinter

def msg():
    print("i'm learning tkinter built in")

root = tkinter.Tk()

label = tkinter.Label(root, text='welcome to the tkinter built in project')
label.pack()

label2 = tkinter.Label(root,text='choose your favorite programming languange',
justify=tkinter.CENTER, 
padx=20)
label2.pack()

tkinter.Radiobutton(root, text='python',padx=20, value= 1).pack(anchor=tkinter.N)
tkinter.Radiobutton(root, text='Javascript',padx=20, value= 2).pack(anchor=tkinter.N)
tkinter.Radiobutton(root, text='C++',padx=20, value= 3).pack(anchor=tkinter.N)
tkinter.Radiobutton(root, text='C',padx=20, value= 4).pack(anchor=tkinter.N)


frame = tkinter.Frame(root)
frame.pack()

button = tkinter.Button(frame, text='quit',fg='black',command=quit)
button.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT)

slogan = tkinter.Button(frame, text='see the message',command=msg)
slogan.pack(side=tkinter.RIGHT)

root.mainloop()
```

---

and the error says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "GUI.py", line 1, in <module>
import tkinter
File "C:\Users\khairunnisa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 39, in <module>
import re
File "C:\Users\khairunnisa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\re.py", line 125, in <module>
import functools
File "C:\Users\khairunnisa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\functools.py", line 21, in <module>
from collections import namedtuple
File "C:\Users\khairunnisa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\collections\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
from operator import itemgetter as _itemgetter, eq as _eq
ImportError: cannot import name 'itemgetter' from 'operator' (D:\JOB\__python\exercise_oop\GUI\operator.py)
```

---

I've tried many times to run this code and the packages are already installed on my PC, but the result is still nothing.
any idea why?

Comment: Hi nsaa95, can we know what command you put in cmd to run your code?

Comment: Your code is not importing `itemgetter` anywhere, atleast from the code you've shown. Can you share the full Traceback error? The code works perfectly fine, I've tested it.

Comment: @Saad I write the command like this `python GUI.py`

Comment: Please don’t put errors message in comment session, you can always edit your post.

Comment: @Saad ohh sorry my bad i'll edit my post first

Comment: @amanb I've already write the traceback on the post

Comment: I ran your code with both ways and had no problems. The problem is that you have a file `operator.py` in the same directory which doesn't let python import `operator` library from the main python lib folder. This is because python first looks for the files in the current directory then the python lib collection. So by changing the name of operator.py in path `D:\JOB\__python\exercise_oop\GUI\operator.py` should solve the issue.

Comment: @Saad my goodness thank you saad…. it's working